# How do you access a custom XHTML attribute with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, attributes

I have the following XHTML:

```
<span id="myid" cus:att="myvalue" xmlns:cus="http://mycompany.com/customnamespace">
</span>
```

Is it possible to access custom attributes with javascript? I have the element that represents the span. Doing `myElement.att` doesn't work, and I can't figure out how to specify the namespace?

Comment: You will need to specify whether the page is being served as text/html or application/xhtml+xml as the answer will be different.

Comment: @Alohci, I'll still be interested in seeing both answers.

Comment: In text/html the namespace is an illusion and what you have is an attribute with a colon in its name. Annakata's answer works. In application/xhtml+xml the namespace is real. I haven't tested, but I expect you will need to getAttributeNS() to access the attribute.

Comment: @Alochi, Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Write that as an answer and it'll get a vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special version of the `getAttribute` method specifically designed for accessing namespaced attributes: `getAttributeNS`. With your example XHTML, the following JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("myid").getAttributeNS("http://mycompany.com/customnamespace", "att");
```

...would return "`myvalue`".

You can read more about the `getAttributeNS` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttributeNS).

Steve

Comment: getAttributeNS is not supported by IE

Comment: Also won't work when the document is XHTML-served-as-HTML. It takes a proper XML parser to support namespaces.

Answer (score 5):

Normally speaking you can access it directly, i.e. `element.attribute` but the namespace slightly complicates this to:

```
element.getAttribute("namespace:attribute") //the nuclear x-browser option
```

so just to be really really clear, that'll be something like:

```
document.getElementById('myid').getAttribute('cus:att')
```

Comment: It works, but he has to get to the element before, which doesn't have an ID, nor class, nor name. Using DOM element as "global" isn't a good practice and you might get burned.

Comment: My problem wasn't getting the element but I will add the id to the question.

Comment: @Bogdan - I'm hardly suggesting he does any global anything, I'm just providing the general form under the (correct) assumption that the OP was capable of selecting the element already

Comment: @annakata Sure, I didn't say you were wrong, but right about now the answer is very good. +1 :)

Comment: I will accept this answer but there is one thing bugging me. To do this I need to know what alias the author chose for the namespace.

Comment: you can of course do some nasty trawling like "var e = document.getElementById("foo"); for(var x in e.attributes) { if(x.match(/att$/)) { alert(e.getAttribute(x)); } }", and it's likely jQuery et al have abstractions which wrap this for you